# how to add kernel command before mysql startup in linux

Tags: mysql, init.d, mysql5

I want to add these commands to the Linux kernel before mysql startup (at boot time):

```
echo never> /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
echo never> /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
```

This is a necessary specification for the application I'm running.

Comment: For what Linux distribution?

Comment: We are using Redhat linux

Answer (score 3):

You could run those commands before MySQL startup by editing the mysql startup scripts. But it would be better to make those settings persistent by editing your `/etc/sysfs.conf`.

If you want to disable transparent hugepage you should add:

`kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled = never`

to your sysctl configuration.

After you edited your sysctl configuration you can reread the configuration with:

`sysctl -p path/to/your/sysctl/config`

The location of the sysctl configuration file depends on the distribution you are using. You should be able to determine the file by looking into the `sysctl` man page `man sysctl`. The path should be listed at the end under `FILES`

Debian based distributions like Ubuntu seem to use `/etc/sysfs.conf`, RedHat based distributions seem to use `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

If you really want to change the setting via startup scripts you could edit your `/etc/rc.local` and add these lines:

```
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
    echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
fi

if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
fi
```

But editing `/etc/sysfs.conf` would be much cleaner.

If you need more information I recommend reading this [https://askubuntu.com/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597372/how-do-i-modify-sys-kernel-mm-transparent-hugepage-enabled) question.

Comment: I've checked and the /etc/sysfs.conf doesn't exist. We are using Redhat Linux. How can we proceed?

Comment: in case of RHEL distributions you need to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Comment: I've done the changes . Now we well see the result on next reboot. Thk u all